# Why does HeidiSQL not show a variable value?

Tags: mysql, database, heidisql

When I run these 2 lines in HeidiSQL:

```
set @tablename = 'if1906_20190522';
select @tablename
```

It shows:

[image]

But when I run same code in the command line, it succeeds and shows the variable value:

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: Looks like your Heidi wraps the variable name with quotes so it is converted to string literal. Check General query log. The problem does not reproduce on my system (MySQL 8.0.12, Heidi 10.1.0.5464 portable). I get the value of the variable. Try to update the app.

Comment: thank you , after i update heidisql to heidisql portable 10.1.0.5464 ,  it show the variable values